# Is set theory taught in middle school in the US?

Tags: education

I recently learned that one of my cousins who is a 7th grader in the United States is learning naive set theory (sets, maps, 1-1, onto maps, relations).  Is this part of middle school math curricula in the US?  So would your average American high school graduate know what a bijection is?

Comment: Not if they use [A Beka Books](http://www.abeka.com/distinctives.aspx).  Usually US grads know a little set theory, enough to deal with domains, ranges, and solution sets and with inverse functions such as in trig. and log/exp. functions.  They are usually familiar with some terms, such as union, intersection, 1-1, onto, but they are not usually familiar with the concept of a bijective function.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there are schools experimenting with such concepts. For example [*Teaching Set Theory to kids in Middle School: ideas?*](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6184326&tstart=0). Also [*How to Teach Set Theory to Grade 6*](http://www.ehow.com/how_12052373_teach-set-theory-grade-6.html). I am not sure what level they are doing, but given the right teacher and students, the kids can amaze. Regards

Answer (score 4):

At present, there is no standard US curriculum. The mathematics taught before college in public schools varies by the state, the district, the city, the school, and even the classroom.

There is a movement to create national standards ("Common Core State Standards for Mathematics") which have been adopted in most of the states, but they do not presently have a corresponding curriculum.

Historically speaking, you might be interested in reading about [New Math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Math), which included a fair amount of naive set theory in its approach to mathematics curricula. Another term worth looking up is [SMSG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMSG).

Generally speaking, however, the answer to both your questions is **no**. Naive set theory is not a standard topic in public schools, and the term "bijection" is almost certainly unknown to the vast, vast majority of high school students in the United States.

Comment: I was already beyond all of them, but I actually had a complete set of SMSG draft textbooks around 1961, when I was in junior high; there were some good things in those books.

Answer (score 2):

In my own (junior) high school (between $5$ and $8$ years ago), there was a mild introduction to these things, but nothing at all on the order of even undergraduate mathematics. As an example, it amounted to having sets $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$ and asking if there could exist a $1$-$1$ map, etc. (This was in a public school, by the way).

From students I've tutored in the past, there also seems to be a similar curriculum, but again, I emphasize that it was not anything extraordinary. This seemed a little long for a comment, and this is my own personal experience. I hope it goes somewhat toward answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught 1-1, onto, and 1-1 and onto functions in high school.  I don't recall learning the terms injection, surjection, or bijection but it's certainly possible (35 years ago!). I was just thinking that bijection was 1-1, but it's 1-1 and onto! As I am an above average graduate, I guess that answers your question!  Even above average high school graduates in the USA do not know what bijection is.  I certainly hope this helps someone.   Thanks for the education!